# Every electron application blank screen when using Wayland

Tags: wayland

In programs made with Electron (eg MongoDB Compass / or my Electron program, etc.), the screen is black or white.

This can be fixed via the "--disable-gpu-compositing" argument to each program. But it's too inconvenient.

I put the argument in ~/.config/electron-flags.conf but it doesn't work. (looking at `strace -f`, that file is not read.)

1. Is there a way to apply arguments to all electron programs or disable GPU?
2. Is there a way to run Electron in Wayland? However, the programs cannot be modified. Because it wasn't made by me.

[image]

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=~%2F.config%2Felectron-flags.conf&ia=web

Comment: As I wrote in the text, electron-flags.conf does not work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wayland#Electron)

> These configuration files only work for the Electron packages in the official repositories and packages that use them. They do not work for packages that bundle their own build of Electron.

However, you can pass the options using `.desktop` files, but you will need to do it per application.